# meterpreter upload command does't work

Tags: meterpreter

I'm trying to upload `nc.exe` on a *Windows 7* system, after having exploited it by using: `exploit/windows/fileformat/ms15_100_mcl_exe`.

After obtaining the session:

```
sessions –l
sessions –i 1
```

I issued the following command to upload the `nc.exe`:

```
upload /usr/share/windows-binaries/nc.exe C:\\windows\\system32
```

but it didn't work, and I got the following error message:

```
[*] uploading  : /usr/share/windows-binaries/nc.exe -> C:\windows\system32
[-] core_channel_open: Operation failed: Access is denied.
```

I've also tried other `meterpreter` commands, and I can say that some commands work, while others don't. For instance:

- `getuid` works
- `getsystem` **doesn't work**
- `shell` works

**Note**: I've previously disabled the *Windows 7* firewall.

Comment: That probably happens because simply you don't have the right permissions to upload your .exe to this particular directory - that's why you get "Access is denied".

Answer (score 2):

You’ll need to elevate your privileges on the target through another exploit. You won’t simply get `NT AUTHORITY/SYSTEM` just because you’ve got a meterpreter session. Try using your shell to send a MSFVenom .exe that will give you UAC Bypass and another Meterpreter. Use that new Meterpreter exploiting the UAC Bypass to `getsystem`and you’ll get the `NT AUTHORITY` every time.

You’ll also want to take advantage of Mimikatz while you have a session open. Make sure you grab any hashes you can to crack offline to further future persistence.

Comment: You’re welcome! There’s a few guides out there that tend to make this challenge a little easier than it is. To truly understand how Windows Internals work from a remote exploitable standpoint. It’s best to start with a basic shell elevate yourself by chaining exploits to get to NT AUTHORITY. You’ll have a much better understanding of exploitation, and pivoting undetected when you start using your sessions to lateral pivot to more machines across a network.

Answer (score 0):

That's as simple as you don't have permissions to write on that folder. Probably, your meterpreter is got under a low priv account. Try to upload to a directory where the user is able to write (maybe it's home dir).